# Remove link from navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation, link

Please anyone help me on this. I want to remove the top link from navigation menu, i found the solution but it removes only parent link, i want tp remove specific link from menu I.e. if users click on it they won't be directed to anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is quite old, since it is still active and none of the answers have been accepted, I would like to answer it.

Since the question is about how to remove a specific link from the main navigation, it can easily be done by javascript (there is no need to modify PHP files for this simple task).

Suppose my HTML code for the navigation is like:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ol class="nav-primary">
        <li class="level0 nav-1 first parent">
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento1/electronics.html" class="level0 has-children">Electronics</a>
            <ul class="level0">
                <li class="level1 nav-1-1 first last"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento1/electronics/mobile.html" class="level1 ">Mobile</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="level0 nav-2 parent">
            <a class="level0 has-children">Furniture</a>
            <ul class="level0">
                <li class="level1 nav-2-1 first last"><a class="level1 ">Chairs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="level0 nav-3 last parent">
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento1/books.html" class="level0 has-children">Books</a>
            <ul class="level0">
                <li class="level1 nav-3-1 first last"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento1/books/story-books.html" class="level1 ">Story Books</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

and I have to remove href link from the second parent, i.e. Furniture, then my javascript code would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#nav .nav-2.level0 a").removeAttr("href");
    });
</script>
```

i.e. The code is simply finding the unique parent element and removing href attribute from it.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento Main Menu Consider has a Categories, Sub Categories.

If you want to remove that you can manage Categories form the Magento Banked it self like **Include in Menu then Select No**. You can set this setting form Magento Back-end **Catalog >> Category >> Select any Category**

But If you want to add any custom in Header then You need to edit the code in Magento **topMenu.phtml** file.

Add the Your link in  `<ul>` Tag.

Add The For Example demo.

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Home');?></a></li>
```

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Some of my categories have sub-categories and others don't. I am trying to navigate to a static block when users click on a specific menu category but it's diverting off to that page, so i'm thinking that if I can remove that link it might allow the static-block to open.

Comment: So to explain further; I need to remove the link of one of my categories. I still want it to show so I don't want to turn it off in the categories section, but I don't want anything to happen when the user clicks. I checked 'topMenu.phtml' but it doesn't show my links in there.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly simple to do

Override one file like this one:-

> `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php`

in your local directory (or preferably in your custom module, needless to say DONT TOUCH CORE)

Find the named

> `function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()`

and just comment out two lines.Please check here my code for this.

```
protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml($category, $level = 0, $isLast = false, $isFirst = false,
    $isOutermost = false, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $noEventAttributes = false)
{
    if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
        return '';
    }
    $html = array();

    // get all children
    // If Flat Data enabled then use it but only on frontend
    $flatHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat');
    if ($flatHelper->isAvailable() && $flatHelper->isBuilt(true) && !Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
        $children = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
        $childrenCount = count($children);
    } else {
        $children = $category->getChildren();
        $childrenCount = $children->count();
    }
    $hasChildren = ($children && $childrenCount);

    // select active children
    $activeChildren = array();
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        if ($child->getIsActive()) {
            $activeChildren[] = $child;
        }
    }
    $activeChildrenCount = count($activeChildren);
    $hasActiveChildren = ($activeChildrenCount > 0);

    // prepare list item html classes
    $classes = array();
    $classes[] = 'level' . $level;
    $classes[] = 'nav-' . $this->_getItemPosition($level);
    if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
        $classes[] = 'active';
    }
    $linkClass = '';
    if ($isOutermost && $outermostItemClass) {
        $classes[] = $outermostItemClass;
        $linkClass = ' class="'.$outermostItemClass.'"';
    }
    if ($isFirst) {
        $classes[] = 'first';
    }
    if ($isLast) {
        $classes[] = 'last';
    }
    if ($hasActiveChildren) {
        $classes[] = 'parent';
    }

    // prepare list item attributes
    $attributes = array();
    if (count($classes) > 0) {
        $attributes['class'] = implode(' ', $classes);
    }
    if ($hasActiveChildren && !$noEventAttributes) {
         $attributes['onmouseover'] = 'toggleMenu(this,1)';
         $attributes['onmouseout'] = 'toggleMenu(this,0)';
    }

    // assemble list item with attributes
    $htmlLi = '<li';
    foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
        $htmlLi .= ' ' . $attrName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attrValue) . '"';
    }
    $htmlLi .= '>';
    $html[] = $htmlLi;

   // $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>'; // Comment this line to remove link
    $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
   // $html[] = '</a>'; //and Comment This line

    // render children
    $htmlChildren = '';
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($activeChildren as $child) {
        $htmlChildren .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
            $child,
            ($level + 1),
            ($j == $activeChildrenCount - 1),
            ($j == 0),
            false,
            $outermostItemClass,
            $childrenWrapClass,
            $noEventAttributes
        );
        $j++;
    }
    if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {
        if ($childrenWrapClass) {
            $html[] = '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
        }
        $html[] = '<ul class="level' . $level . '">';
        $html[] = $htmlChildren;
        $html[] = '</ul>';
        if ($childrenWrapClass) {
            $html[] = '</div>';
        }
    }

    $html[] = '</li>';

    $html = implode("\n", $html);
    return $html;
}
```